# Command swiftc crashes on Xcode10

Tags: swift, compilation, xcode10

I need to do some non-trivial refactoring in a mixed objc & swift project.

But after some code editing, the new Xcode10 compiler crashes every time.

I'm sure there are some errors in my refactored code, but the compiler is not able to show where. It just says :

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

So frustrating! Impossible to debug!

Of course, I updated the whole project to Swift 4.2, so I cannot roll back to Xcode 9.4 :(

Is this a bug? Is there some compilation parameters to make swiftc giving better errors?

Thanks

EDIT: just tried with Xcode 10.1 (beta), and the same problem persists.

EDIT2: after investigations, it seems the problem occurs when I import the objc generated interface header file (the one generally finishing with *-Swift.h). Still no solution.

Comment: I found xcode 10 is buggy crashing happens sometime suggestion not appearing and with scene editor crash every time  so  I am not using xcode10  i rolled back to 9.3  As you have converted to latest swift 4.2 so You can't roll back hard luck :(

Comment: Well, this is just the bling guess, but maybe after refactoring you have two classes with the same name? 
Or if you have bridging headers and changed their location and forgot to update info.plist file?

Comment: @ShalvaAvanashvili, currently i'm trying to convert objc files to swift. Of course I removed the old objc classes while creating their swift version. But compiler always crashes before giving any clue of what is messin up.